# BigQuery Sum Columns with Case When

Tags: sql, if-statement, google-bigquery, sum

I want to calculate the sum of the column with an if condition. Here my code:

```
SELECT 

SUM(CASE WHEN properties = 'revenue' THEN property.value ELSE 0 END) AS TotalRevenue,

FROM deneme-319116.events.eventstable;
```

Sample data:

Properties  Property.value

Search   /   null

Revenue   /  15

Count    /   25

Revenue  /   40

I need to find 55 (15+40) as a result
In my eventstable I have columns properties and the property.value. I want to sum the property.value values that properties equal to 'revenue' but bigquery gives error: 'cannot acces field key on a value with type ARRAYvalue....

Plz help, thx

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Comment: there is a mentioning of `key` field in error message - but there is none in the query you presented. so yo might want to improve your question and/or provide more details

Comment: still not clear! where is the `array` here? where is `key` field`? ... show the schema with field types, etc.

Comment: I dont know any of these

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . then you need to `unnest()`.  If you want the sum *per row* in the original table:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(el.value)
        FROM unnest(et.properties) el
        WHERE el.name = 'revenue'  -- or whatever the name is
       ) as TotalRevenue,
FROM deneme-319116.events.eventstable et;
```

If you want the *overall* sum over all rows:

```
SELECT SUM(el.value) as TotalRevenue,
FROM deneme-319116.events.eventstable et CROSS JOIN
     unnest(et.properties) el
 WHERE el.name = 'revenue'  -- or whatever the name is
```

Comment: Thx for the help but I couldnt understand the el.value and et.properties what they represent.

Comment: @BahadirAyan . . . You don't provide clear sample data, so it is a little hard to see what the columns are actually named.